# Linux based 10G ethernet driver can't send nor receive anything to/from wire

Tags: linux, driver, ethernet

I am currently developing a 10g Ethernet driver (chip is Intel 82599), I referring to ixgbe and trimming it, the problem is that it can't send nor receive anything to/from wire. And below is what I have done so far:

1, The low level initialization seems OK, the Link status Up, and the auto-negotiation is done successfully and ends up 10Gb.

2, DMA mapping for Rx/Tx ring is done via pci_alloc_consistent() successfully, and before that pci_set_dma_mask (64bit) is called to insure that the whole address range is reachable.

3, When Ping, tx descriptor is consuming, and one transmit interrupt received per packet sent (by DMA chip)

4, Loop back LPBK is set for diagnostics, no receive interrupt is invoked at all.

Could it be possible that DMA has problem accessing host memory (although map is done)? and How to verify that the physical address is reachable by DMA chip on the NIC ?

somehow stuck here, and really needs advice on this low level trouble shooting ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't tell if you're brilliant, or trolling. Why aren't you using [this](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=14687&lang=eng&OSVersion=Linux*&DownloadType=) driver? Especially since (per the link), The latest version and earlier versions of this driver are available from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/files/82599%20Developer%20Manual/).

Comment: Although it sounds a little bit wired, but we have to adjust the driver to something fulfill our needs.